# jQuery.ajax is not a function TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm not sure why my code is bringing up an error. What have I got wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $( document ).ready(function() {
        var logResp = $('#food-hygiene');

        logResp.ajax({
                        url: "food-hygiene.html",
                        async: false,
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "string"
                    }).done( function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    })
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div id="food-hygiene">Loading...</div>
         </div>

        </div>
        <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

UPDATE: As pointed out by Satpal, there are two references to jQuery. The lower one is a slim version which doesn't support jQuery.

Comment: Instead of `logResp.ajax` use `$.ajax`

Comment: Instead of `logResp.ajax({` do `$.ajax({`

Comment: The *"slim"* version of jQuery doesn't include the `$.ajax` API. Use full version

Comment: charlietfl: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js - is this slim?

Comment: No since it doesn't have "slim" in the file name

Comment: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js which is added at bottom of page which is override previous loaded ibrary

Comment: Ah. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are creating an object and trying to use it as a prefix for `ajax` which is wrong
2. Add only one jQuery library either `jquery-3.2.1.min.js` or `jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js`
3. Put script code down on the page and check. (Or you can leave it there also)

Do like below:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div id="food-hygiene">Loading...</div>
         </div>

        </div>
        <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         <script>
          $( document ).ready(function() {
            var logResp = $('#food-hygiene');

            logResp.ajax({
                            url: "food-hygiene.html",
                            async: false,
                            type: "GET",
                            dataType: "string"
                        }).done( function(data) {
                            alert(data);
                        })
          });
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`logResp` it contains the instance of the `#food-hygiene` element you select using this statement: `$('#food-hygiene');`.

Replace this code:

```
logResp.ajax({
                    url: "food-hygiene.html",
                    async: false,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "string"
                }).done( function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                })
```

With this:

```
jQuery
    .ajax(
        {
            url: "food-hygiene.html",
            async: false,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "string"
         }
    )
    .done(
        function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    );
```

Comment: It solves one issue but doesn't solve the OP's problem.

Comment: You might want to check that the code is actually solving the OP's problem before saying that @BlindRoach.

Comment: We all come here to learn and share our knowledge, and I feel like the whole downvoting system was poorly made. I think you should have pointed that out as comment, the answer isn't something that was scribbled in a few seconds, its well enough constructed and I think he would edit/remove after a heads up. Didn't mean to offend by my comment, I just think the downvote should be reserved for ignorant out of context answers that don't even aim to fix the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

Just replace:

'src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"'

with

'src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"'

in script tag and add it in head tad

Answer (score 1):

It seems the jQuery file is not loaded properly, I have tried without another `<link>` tag and the code doesn't throw any errors:

Also `$('#food-hygiene')` doesn't have a method `ajax()` put [`$`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) does.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $.ajax({
    url: "food-hygiene.html",
    async: false,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "string"
  }).done(function(data) {
    alert(data);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>-->

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div id="food-hygiene">Loading...</div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
  <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```